# React Child component does not rerender on prop change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

I have a parent component

```
// generate an array of objects, which gets passed the the CalendarDateGrid Component
const calculatedCalendarData = (startDate, endDate) => {
  return [
    { calcNormalOrderElectoralBoard: calcNormalOrderElectoralBoard(endDate) },
    { calcNormalDiploma: calcNormalDiploma(startDate) },
  ];
};

export default function Home() {
  const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(new Date());
  const [endDate, setEndDate] = useState(new Date());
  const [selectedRegion, setSelectedRegion] = useState(
    questions[2].selections[0]
  );
  const [electoralProcess, setElectoralProcess] = useState(
    questions[3].selections[0]
  );
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [calendarData, setCalendarData] = useState(calculatedCalendarData(startDate, endDate));

  return (
    <div>
      <main className="font-heebo">
        <div className="max-w-full mx-auto">
          <Calendar
            startDate={startDate}
            onDateChange={setStartDate}
            endDate={endDate}
            onEndDateChange={setEndDate}
            selectedRegion={selectedRegion}
            setSelectedRegion={setSelectedRegion}
            electoralProcess={electoralProcess}
            setElectoralProcess={setElectoralProcess}
            calendarData={calendarData}
            setCalendarData={setCalendarData}
            setLoading={setLoading}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="max-w-full mx-auto">
          <CalendarDateGrid
            data={calendarData}
            setData={calculatedCalendarData}
            isLoading={loading}
          />
        </div>
      </main>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Inside my Calendar component (which is a form), I am saving the data and passing that data to my parent

```
<div className="py-14">
  <div
    onClick={() => setCalendarData}
    className="cursor-pointer bg-white w-72 mx-auto text-center text-wahl-red rounded"
  >
    <span className="inline-block border-wahl-red rotate-180 border w-5 align-middle" />
    <span type="button" className="inline-block px-3 py-2 text-lg">
      calculate date
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

After that I am trying to pass that data to my CalendarDateGrid component.
Which basically shall take the data and generate a layout mapping through that data:

```
export default function CalendarDateGrid({ data, isLoading }) {
  const [calendarData, setCalendarData] = useState(data);

  useEffect(() => {
    setCalendarData(data);
  }, [data]);

  return (
    <div className="w-4/5 2xl:w-2/3 mx-auto pb-20">
      {isLoading && (
        <ul
          role="list"
          className="mt-3 grid grid-cols-1 gap-5 sm:gap-12 md:grid-cols-2 xl:grid-cols-3"
        >
          {calendarData.map((calendarItem) => (
...
```

The issues is that my child component does not update if the data do get updated. I am trying to update using useEffect but that does not work.

Comment: What is the type of `calenderData` that you're passing down to your child component? Is it Object or Array? Also if you could provide a sandbox, it would help to answer your question faster.

Comment: Its an array of objects

Comment: How is calculateCalender changed? setCalculateCalender( newArray) ?

Comment: Is "calculateCalendar" a state variable? If it is not, then will be no re-render con the parent, therefore, no prop updated for the child to update. If this is the case, let me know and I can set it as an answer.

Comment: I will rephrase my question

Comment: @JuanChaher I update my question with all information, you are welcome to have a look on it :)

Answer (score 0):

The `useEffect` hook implement a shallow comparison on the value passed as a dependency. So If you want to pass an Object or an Array as your dependency, you should define what it exactly is.

- **Object Dependecy**

For example, if you have an object as your state, you should define which property to be considered as a dependency:

```
const [user, setUser] = useState({
  name: '',
  age: ''
})

// If you want to run the useEffect on every changes of user
useEffect(() => {
  console.log("a property in object is changing")
}, [...user])

// If you want to run the useEffect only on change of user's age
useEffect(() => {
  console.log("user's age is changing")
}, [user.age])
```

- **Array Dependecy**

```
const [data, setData] = useState([])

// If event that cause change in data, affect on its length
useEffect(() => {
  console.log("array's length is changing")
}, [data.length])
```

If the `data`'s length does not change, or `data` is an array of objects that inner fields may change, you can use one of the following ways:

1. Comparing the `data` value with its previous value by using `JSON.stringify(data)`

```
const [data, setData] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
  console.log("array is changing")
}, [JSON.stringify(data)])
```

2. You can use [use-deep-compare-effect](https://github.com/kentcdodds/use-deep-compare-effect) package, or write your own custom hook if you what exactly is the properties inside of the nested objects of `data` array.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I updated my question with all information of my component (nearly all) you can have a look at it if you like to